# Get two numbers from a string

Tags: python, string

I need to extract two numbers inside a string. They can look like this:

```
(0,0)
(122,158)
(1,22)
(883,8)
etc...
```

So I want to get the first number before the comma and the number after the comma and store them in variables. I can get the first number like this:

```
myString.split(',')[0][1:])
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the next number.

---

> Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Use Regular Expressions https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: In your posted code `[0]` refers to the first number. So just do `[1]` to get the second number.

Comment: That also prints the parenthesis. I just want the numbers.

Comment: @m.o `myString.split(',')[1][:-1]` just about the same as your own code! You were close.

Comment: Isn't it easier to first remove the parentheses, then do the split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with something like

```
myVar.split(',')[0][1:] # = 122 for the string in the second line
myVar.split(',')[1][:-1] # = 158 for the string in the second line
```

This should be the easiest way to do this

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin I realised this as soon as i posted, my fingers were faster than my brain :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of the parentheses, split the string, and convert each item to an int:

```
a, b = [int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(',')]
```

Of course, if you **absolutely sure** about the string's format, and don't care about security, you could just `eval` the string:

```
a, b = eval(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert your string into a tuple. This will also take care about extra whitespace like `'( 123, 158)'`.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> tup = literal_eval('(122,158)')
>>> tup[0]
122
>>> tup[1]
158
```

Or just:

```
>>> first, second = literal_eval('(122,158)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi assignment, [stripping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) the parentheses and splitting will do:

```
a, b = myString.lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(',')
# a, b = map(int, (a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myVar.split(',')[1][:-1])
```

will get you the second number

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* one-liner would be

```
a, b = (myString[1:-1].split(',')[0], myString[1:-1].split(',')[1])
```

Gets rid of the parentheses, then splits at the comma.